# Android studio retrolambda debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, retrolambda

I'm talking about debugging in Android Studio. 
Is it possible to access outer class variable inside of retrolambda code?

For example:

```
MyActivity extends Activity {
    MyObject mObject;
    View mView;
    ...

    mView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            ...
            //here in debug I can't see mObject: "this" is not available
            mObject.myMethod();
            ...

        });
   ...
}
```